# Wordpress Custom Metabox Box Array

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, meta-boxes

I'm trying to create a custom meta box in Wordpress for storing additional links to an article. Because I don't know how much Links there'll be in the end I created a button for adding fields to the meta box.

[This is how it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fA9xC.png)

New fields are rendered with javascript, the stored ones with php. This is not as DRY as it could be, but I didn't find another way and it should work.

The code runs without throwing an error but the array isn't saved correctly. `print_r($current_svl_additional_links);` just prints "Array" at the moment. Something that's also bugging me: `data-count="<?php echo count($current_svl_additional_links); ?>"` is "1" even if the post is not saved yet. Help is much appreciated! This is how far I got:

```
/**
 * Add meta box to
 * svl_editions post type for additional links
 * @param post $post The post object
 * @link https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/add_meta_boxes
 */
function svl_add_meta_box_additional_links($post) {
  add_meta_box(
    'svl_meta_box_additional_links',
    __('Additional Links', 'stilvorlagen-functions'),
    'svl_render_meta_box_additional_links',
    'svl_referents',
    'side',
    'low'
  );
}
add_action('add_meta_boxes_svl_referents', 'svl_add_meta_box_additional_links');


/**
 * Render part of custom field meta box for
 * svl_editions post type for additional links
 * look in scripts/svl-admin-additional-links.php for the rest
 * @param post $post The post object
 */
function svl_render_meta_box_additional_links($post) {
  wp_nonce_field(plugin_basename(__FILE__), 'svl_meta_box_additional_links_nonce');

  $current_svl_additional_links = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_svl_additional_links', true);
  print_r($current_svl_additional_links);

  ?>
  <div class="EntriesContainer" data-count="<?php echo count($current_svl_additional_links); ?>" id="itemsList">
    <?php
    $i = 0;
    if (count($current_svl_additional_links) > 0) {
      foreach((array)$current_svl_additional_links as $current_svl_additional_link) {
        if (isset($current_svl_additional_link['link_name']) || isset($current_svl_additional_link['link_url'])) {
          ?>
          <div class="svl-additional-link-item">
            <p><strong><?php echo $i; ?>. Link </strong><span class="remove"> (Entfernen)</span></p>

            <label for="svl_additional_links[<?php echo $i ?>][link_name]"><?php _e('Link-Name', 'stilvorlagen-functions') ?></label>
            <input type="text" id="svl_additional_links[<?php echo $i ?>][link_name]" name="svl_additional_links[<?php echo $i ?>][link_name]" value="<?php echo esc_attr($current_svl_additional_link['link_name']) ?>" size="15" />

            <label for="svl_additional_links[<?php echo $i ?>][link_url]"><?php _e('Link-URL', 'stilvorlagen-functions') ?></label>
            <input type="text" id="svl_additional_links[<?php echo $i ?>][link_url]" name="svl_additional_links[<?php echo $i ?>][link_url]" value="<?php echo esc_attr($current_svl_additional_link['link_url']) ?>" size="15" />
            <br/>
          </div>
          <?php
          ++$i;
        }
      }
    } ?>
  </div>
  <div class=add-additional-link-action>
    <button type="button" class="button" id="addNewItem">Add New Link</button>
  </div><?php
}


/**
 * Store custom field meta box data
 * @param int $post_id The post ID.
 * @link https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post
 */
function svl_save_meta_box_additional_links($post_id) {
  // verify taxonomies meta box nonce
  if (!is_valid_user_input(array('svl_meta_box_additional_links_nonce'), $post_id)) {
    return;
  }

  // Make sure that everything is set.
  if (! isset($_POST['svl_additional_links'])) {
    SVLMessagePipeline::push_error('Input fields missing.');
    delete_post_meta($post_id, 'svl_additional_links');
    return;
  }

  // store custom fields values
  $additional_links = sanitize_text_field($_POST['svl_additional_links']);

  update_post_meta($post_id, '_svl_additional_links', $additional_links);
}
add_action('save_post_svl_referents', 'svl_save_meta_box_additional_links');
```

and some javascript to render new fields if the button is pressed

```
/**
 * Render part of the custom field meta box for
 * svl_editions post type for additional links
 * look in svl-post-meta.php for the rest
 * @param post $post The post object
 */
(function($) {
  // Namespace-object to keep global scope clean:
  var add_additional_link = (function () {
    "use strict";
    var pub = {}, // Stands for public, gets returned
      timer, addNewItemButton, totalItems

    pub.init = function () {
      addNewItemButton = $("#addNewItem");
      $(addNewItemButton).on('click', pub.addNewItem);
      totalItems = parseInt($('#itemsList').attr('data-count'));
    };

    $(".remove").live('click', function() {
        $(this).parent().parent().remove();
    });

    $(document).ready( function () {
        pub.init();
    });

    pub.addNewItem = function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();

      ++totalItems;

      var $newItem =
        '<div class="svl-additional-link-item">' +
          '<p><strong>' + totalItems + '. Link</strong><span class="remove"> (Entfernen)</span></p>' +

          '<label for="svl_additional_links[' + totalItems + '][link_name]">Link-Name</label>' +
          '<input type="text" id="svl_additional_links[' + totalItems + '][link_name]" name="svl_additional_links[' + totalItems + '][link_name]" value="" size="15" />' +

          '<label for="svl_additional_links[' + totalItems + '][link_url]">Link-URL</label>' +
          '<input type="text" id="svl_additional_links[' + totalItems + '][link_url]" name="svl_additional_links[' + totalItems + '][link_url]" value="" size="15" />' +
          '<br/>'
        '</div>';

      $('#itemsList').append($newItem);
    };

    return pub;
  }());
}(jQuery))
```